# Choosing right power supply

Tags: power-supply, power

I'm looking for source which simply described how can choose right power supply, for example it possible to use one power supply with same voltage and higher amperage insted using sevseral power supply with lower amperage? If it is not possible explain for what and if its possible under which conditions it is possible

Comment: I think this is the second time this question has been asked today.

Comment: Please led me to see this question